# Are you obligated to ask forgiveness from someone if they don't know you sinned against them?

Tags: halacha, repentance-teshuvah

According to the laws of repentance, is one obligated to ask forgiveness for interpersonal sins the victim is unaware of?

For instance, suppose someone cursed their fellow "behind their back", and in private. Is that person obligated to inform the person of his deeds and ask forgiveness?

Comment: This is a machlokes between the MB and forgot who the other one is ,maybe Netziv . Have to find source

Comment: @sam - The other is Reb Yisroel Salater who is reported to not have given a Haskama on Sefer Chofetz Chaim because this requirement was written in it.

Comment: We must have this question already

Comment: This story is brought is Sefer Perach Mateh Aharon pg 88, in the name of Rav Hunter. Also requoted in Sefer Kedosh Yisroel pg. רכז.

Comment: @פריזהב pretty close ,now rings a bell ,tx

Comment: Opposite question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/85034/

Comment: @donielf The question isn’t about winning against someone you don’t know, it’s sinning against someone who doesn’t know you sinned against them. In theory you can inform them, but is that a mitzvah?

Comment: @Fei23 You can inform them on an anonymous site also. https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4754/